# JQuery/Javascript block scaling

Tags: javascript, jquery, scale, effect

I have some div-block. I need in scaling it's own size. Like in MacOS dock panel, when icon is hovered. Can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes you can:

html:

```
<div class="scaleMe">&nbsp</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){ /* makes sure your dom is ready */
   $('div.scaleMe').hover(function(){
                       $(this).stop(false, true).animate({width:'50px', height:'50px'}, 1000) /* makes the div big on hover, and .stop() makes sure the annimation is not looping*/
                    },function(){
                       $(this).stop(false, true).animate({width:'20px', height:'20px'}, 600) /* goes back to normal state */
                    })
})
```

here you can find a nice example of a OSX like dock made with jQuery:
http://www.ndesign-studio.com/blog/css-dock-menu

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
$("#myDiv").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).css({height : scaled_height, width : scaled_width});
    }, 
    function(){
        $(this).css({height : original_height, width : original_width});
    }
);
```

Comment: You could get rid of half of the `.css()` statements by grouping them together: `$(this).css({ height: originalHeight, width: originalWidth });`

Comment: @Mathias Bynens, Thanks for the tip!  I'll change that right now.

Comment: Good point, I changed my example and actually found a good article about the differences http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1805-jQuery-Events-MouseOver-MouseOut-vs-MouseEnter-MouseLeave.htm

Answer (score 0):

I got this solution from http://jsbin.com/ecuzof/1/edit/.  Acknowledgement goes to the author for getting going!  I found the link from http://forum.jquery.com/topic/i-want-to-resize-or-scale-the-div-on-hover.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <title>Zoom DIV on Hover</title>
        <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            body{
                font-size:162.5%;
            }
        </style>
        <style>
            .sectionToZoomOnHover {
                display: table-cell;
                text-align: center;
                vertical-align: middle;
                width: 200px;
                height: 50px;
                margin: 1em;
                padding: 1.2em;
                border: 1px solid gray;
                background: yellow;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="sectionToZoomOnHover">
            Hover me. I'll grow
        </div>

        <script>
            $(".sectionToZoomOnHover").hover(
                function() {
                    $(this).stop().animate(
                        {
                            width: 360,
                            height: 100,
                            backgroundColor: "lightBlue",
                            fontSize: "3em"
                        }
                    );
                }, function() {
                    $(this).stop().animate(
                        {
                            width: 200,
                            height: 50,
                            backgroundColor: "yellow",
                            fontSize: "1em"
                        }
                    );
                }
            );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, I haven't figured out how to zoom so the center point of the DIV remains as it is, which is the effect that I really would like, too.